# How can I easily find all languages a show has been dubbed into?

Tags: resources

I usually only watch anime with the original Japanese voice actors, since I've had bad experiences with dubs in the past. However, I'm sometimes interested in watching a show dubbed in something that isn't Japanese, and moreover, I want to know if there are any alternatives to English dubs.

Is there any site that will let me see *all* languages a show has been dubbed into efficiently?

- MyAnimeList gives the voice actors in various languages for characters. However, this information is often incomplete. For instance, I just looked at [the page for Nagisa Misumi](https://web.archive.org/web/20150429123839/http://myanimelist.net/character/5449/Nagisa_Misumi) of *Pretty Cure* and noticed that no Cantonese voice actress is listed, even though a Cantonese dub exists.
- A Wikipedia article in some language `foo` for a show will sometimes list any voice actors for the dub in `foo` in addition to the Japanese voice actors. Information about dubs in other languages is generally lacking. This would mean that I would have to check (and be able to read) each Wikipedia page in each potentially interesting language. Moreover, I would have to carefully check shows one at a time, which is not convenient.
- Similarly, wikis for a series *sometimes* contain information about dubs (e.g. a [*Sailor Moon* wiki](http://wikimoon.org/index.php?title=Sailor_Moon_in_Korea) I found). As a general rule however, this is not the case. For instance, a Cantonese dub for *Revolutionary Girl Utena* exists, but there is no mention of it in [a fan-made wiki](http://utena.wikia.com/).

In the case of Cantonese (or even Mandarin), I can usually "guess" that older, more prominent shows will have a dub. However, I find it difficult to do the same for other languages that I might be interested in (e.g. German), and at any rate, it'd be nice to not have to rely on my guesswork.

Comment: I tend to use [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) and look for the *"[LANGUAGE] cast"* section. every series always has Japanese Cast (yes, even RWBY) so it's in Japanese, if there is an English Cast that means it's been dubbed in english

Comment: @Memor-X: hmmm, I tried [_Pretty Cure_ there](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911182831/http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3434) and still didn't find information about a Cantonese dub. It could be that most sites (at least in English) are reliant on user contributions and that users aren't familiar with dubs in languages they don't know . . . I wonder if maybe there might be more centralisation on Japanese / etc. sites?

Comment: @Maroon "All languages" is going to be tough. MAL is pretty terrible for this; you mostly get European languages and Korean there, and not even very comprehensively. ANN does better, but still has a European-language bias. I imagine it's inherently difficult to know whether a dub for a given language exists - you'd probably have to scour news sources for all potential target languages to see where dubs do and don't exist, and I don't think anyone's getting paid to do that.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Japanese-language sites that do better, though. There isn't much interest in dubs among Japanese viewers in general (aside from perhaps English-language dubs, which, curiously, seem to be of some interest to Japanese people seeking to improve their English).

Comment: @senshin that makes some sense; when I was learning Spanish, I read *Harry Potter y la piedra filosofal*, the Spanish translation of the first Harry Potter book.

Comment: I posted the same question for movies and series in general on the Movies&TV Stack Exchange: "[Where to look up which dubs exist? (That is: Translations into which languages are there of a movie or series?)](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65940/10018)"

Answer (score 1):

## Translating web pages automatically with Google Translate°

> This would mean that I would have to check (*and be able to read*) each […] page in each potentially interesting language.

Google Translate goes a long way in helping that.  Although unfortunately its translations of Asian languages can still be tricky to understand.

If you use the Google Chrome browser, it *should* automatically offer to translate foreign pages (but does not consistently do so for me).
If you want to test that, here's the Cantonese Wikipedia page for Pretty Cure:
https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_Precure!

If you use another browser, e.g. Mozilla Firefox, or Chrome doesn't offer the translation by itself:

#### Put this before the URL to translate:                               https://translate.google.com/translate?&u=

Example: https://translate.google.com/translate?&u=https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_Precure!

---

° Sorry this is not an answer to the question, but I find it so important, that I wanted it to be more visible.  (And then I ended up writing more than would fit into a comment.)  If the community objects, I will move this to a comment.

In relation to the question, the translation enables you to apply the useful approach, suggested by the asker, of consulting the anime's page on the Wikipedia(s) of your desired dub language(s).  (Or opening foreign Google results.)

Comment: The best way I believe to be the [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) "[LANGUAGE] cast" sections  for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

## Googling specific dub languages

Example: [https://www.google.com/search?q="cantonese"+dubbed+pretty+cure](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cantonese%22+dubbed+pretty+cure)

(Putting single search terms within `"` double quotes  makes sure they are actually present in the results.  (You could also apply that to the word `dubbed`.))

This tends to return YouTube videos of the Opening songs if the dub exists.  (Don't get confused by fandubs though.)

<sub>(I know this approach is super obvious, but I think it should be here for the sake of completeness and so it can be ranked against other approaches through votes.)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

## For English dubs

**https://myanimelist.net/animelist/Universalx?status=7**
is an astonishingly comprehensive list maintained by a single user.
It has 1973 entries as of November 2020 and includes currently airing series.

Comment: Does someone have an idea what might have been the reasons for downvoting this answer?  I’m genuinely interested!